# Making a single-input DeMultiplexer

Tags: vhdl, quartus

I wrote a code to make a 3-1 multiplexer with 1 selector which works by selector pulses,and Here's the code i wrote below.
However, the the output assigns to the input and its chance ONLY During the if condition. How to make it always assigns to that value whenever it changes ?

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity selector is
port( ip,selec: in std_logic;
        a,b,c: inout std_logic);
end selector;

architecture Behaviour of selector is
signal temp : std_logic;
begin
    process(selec)
    begin
        if (selec'EVENT and selec ='1') then
            if(a = ip) then
                temp<= b;
            elsif (b = ip) then
                temp <= c;
            else
                temp <= a;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
end if;
    
end Behaviour;
```

I'm using only ModelSim since i don't have access to hardware to test on :(

Answer (score 0):

In your process you have only included selec in the sensitivity list.  Therefore the assignment to temp only takes place upon event on selec.

This would be much better suited to a conditional assignment.
[https://www.ics.uci.edu/~jmoorkan/vhdlref/cond_s_a.html](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Ejmoorkan/vhdlref/cond_s_a.html)

```
signal_name <= expression_1 when condition_1 else
               expression_2 when condition_2 else
               expression_3 ;
```

Comment: This expression will not work since I'm assigning input to go out from a specific output ( a De Multiplexer ) and it can't be applied on a sequential circuit, the one I'm trying to make here

Comment: Have you tried adding the other signals to the process sensitivity list?